# Verilog code generating 'dont care' for iterations

Tags: verilog

I have written the following code to generate sine angles using Cordic algorithm. The following is a part of code which generates the x,y,z co-ordinates for a given angle.

```
genvar i;
generate
  for (i=0; i < (width-1); i=i+1) begin 
    wire z_sign;
    wire signed [width-1:0] x_shr, y_shr;
    assign x_shr = x[i] >>> i; // signed shift right
    assign y_shr = y[i] >>> i;

    initial begin
      #20 $display("x_shr = %b, y_shr = %b ",x_shr,y_shr);
    end

    //the sign of the current rotation angle

    assign z_sign = z[i][31];
    always @(posedge clock) begin
      // add/subtract shifted data
      x[i+1] <= z_sign ? x[i] + y_shr : x[i] - y_shr;
      y[i+1] <= z_sign ? y[i] - x_shr : y[i] + x_shr;
      z[i+1] <= z_sign ? z[i] + atan_table[i] : z[i] - atan_table[i];

      #25 $display("x[%d] = %b",i,x[i]);

    end
  end
endgenerate
```

The inputs given were :

```
x_shr = 'b0000000000000100;
y_shr = 'b0000000000000000;
```

z_sign is the sign of z[i]:

```
z[0] = 'b00100000000000000000000000000000;
width = 16;
x[0] <= 'b0000000000000100;
y[0] <= 'b0;
```

All the declarations are as follows

```
parameter width = 16;
// Inputs
input clock;
input signed [width-1:0] x_start,y_start;
reg signed [width-1:0] x [0:width-1];
reg signed [width-1:0] y [0:width-1];
reg signed [31:0] z [0:width-1];
```

But the output i am getting is

```
x_shr = 0000000000000100, y_shr = 0000000000000000 
x_shr = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, y_shr = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 
x_shr = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, y_shr = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 
x_shr = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, y_shr = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 
x_shr = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, y_shr = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 
x_shr = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, y_shr = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 
x_shr = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, y_shr = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 
x_shr = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, y_shr = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 
x_shr = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, y_shr = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 
x_shr = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, y_shr = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 
x_shr = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, y_shr = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 
x_shr = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, y_shr = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 
x_shr = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, y_shr = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 
x_shr = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, y_shr = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 
x_shr = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, y_shr = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 
x[ 14] = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
x[ 13] = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
x[ 12] = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
x[ 11] = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
x[ 10] = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
x[  9] = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
x[  8] = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
x[ 7] = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
x[ 6] = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
x[ 5] = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
x[ 4] = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
x[ 3] = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
x[ 2] = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
x[ 1] = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
x[ 0] = 0000000000000100
```

Why am I getting `x` after single iteration?

Comment: `x` as an output means an unknown value, it is not initialised or has multiple conflicting drivers.

Comment: Yes, that is true, but i checked, there are no additional drivers

Comment: Using delays inside a generate does not look correct.

Answer (score 1):

if you display value of Z then you will see that Z is not being provided an initial value. This will eventually drive X and Y to 'x also. so, provide an initial value to Z also.

Comment: But z is initialised as `z[0] = 'b00100000000000000000000000000000;` so rest of the z[i] should calculate themselves right? Also x and y are initialised, i will edit the post to include that info

Comment: How about `atan_table` ? Can you dump out values of x,y and z at intervals of time stamp 0,10,20,25 ?